# .each in Phantom.js with Cheerio - any alternative?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, phantomjs, cheerio

I'm looking for some function that would allow me to reiterate through the div elements scraped by PhantomJs (which uses jQuery-like syntax), but **one by one** - not all at the same time like `.each` seems to be doing. So I guess I need it to run syncroniously.

At the moment my code looks something like this

```
 page.open("https://www.google.com" + expandedurl, function (status) {
 console.log("opened google knowledge graph ", status);
    page.evaluate(function () { return document.body.innerHTML; }, function (result) {
       var $ = cheerio.load(result);
       $(".kltat").each(function() {
         var link = $(this);
         var text = link.text();
         launch(text);
       });
       ph.exit();
       // Move on to the next one
  });
});
```

I need something that would not launch all of the `each` iterations at the same time. Maybe there's some way of reiterating I could use that would not work asynchroniously - that's what i need...

Comment: You can always simply use a `for` loop, but by your description the problem seems to actually be elsewhere. What kind of an issue are you running into?

Comment: Cheerio does not launch all `each` iterations at the same time. Proof: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/master/lib/api/traversing.js#L291-L295

Answer (score 0):

If `launch` is something asynchronous and is able to take a callback, then

Use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for this:

```
var async = require('async');

var $ = cheerio.load(result);
var callbacks = [];
$(".kltat").each(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var text = link.text();
    callbacks.push(function(cb){
        launch(text, cb);
    });
});

async.series(callbacks, function(){
    ph.exit();
});
```

Otherwise, you can either use a static wait amount:

```
callbacks.push(function(cb){
    launch(text);
    setTimeout(function(){
        cb(null);
    });
});
```

or use something like [waitFor](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) to wait for an external condition triggered through `launch`.